# CSS: background-image URL - only local files allowed?

Tags: css

Is local file the only allowed as url attribute value in CSS background-image property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any URL supported

Answer (score 2):

It can be from anywhere, just make sure your path is correct.

```
background-image: url(images/file.jpg);
```

For example would be to an image in the 'images' folder. ../ will help you navigate back between folders but I try to stay away from it for larger sites. Absolute URLs should work too, but should also not be relied on in case the image is removed.

Answer (score 1):

No, did you try it with a full URL?

Answer (score 0):

I believe  you can put any image file as a background-image.
You just have to specify the full path: 
http://soundslikedesign.co.uk/images/photography/QE2%20and%20Chopper.jpg

```
.item {backround-image: url(http://soundslikedesign.co.uk/images/photography/QE2%20and%20Chopper.jpg)}
```